# reading csv with values with international numbers

Tags: python, csv, python-polars

I am trying to read a CSV which contains numbers in a European manner for instance:

```
"COL_A", "COL_B"
"ID_A", "47,37"
```

I am reading it with a code like:

```
pl.read_csv(inputfile, dtypes={COL_B:float}, infer_schema_length=200)
```

and I get an error
`exceptions.ComputeError: could not parse "47,37" as dtype Float64 at` ...

Is there an easy way to import it adequately (as a float of 47.37)?

I am using polars version 0.15.14

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6698) regarding this feature. For now you could import with pandas first and use [from_pandas](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.from_pandas.html#polars.from_pandas), or use pyarrow as suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6698#issuecomment-1419770391)

Comment: Thanks,  looks like bad timing. It seems that I will default back to pandas and wait.

Comment: Would this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71753605/polars-read-csv-with-german-number-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Despite the implementation with libraries, why don't you try something simpler?

replace "," with "." using regex() while importing csv in **javascript:**

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (row) => {
    const amount = parseFloat(row.amount.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    console.log(amount);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('CSV file successfully processed.');
  });
```

***in Python:***

```
import polars as pl

def get_european_number(value: str) -> float:
    return float(value.replace(",", "."))

inputfile = "data.csv"
df = pl.read_csv(inputfile, dtype={"amount": pl.Float64}, parse_options=pl.csv.ParseOptions(parse_func=get_european_number))
```

dtype parameter needed to tell Polars should be parsed as a float64 data type.

Comment: Thanks, when I try: it says that `pl.csv.ParseOptions` is not in the pl scope. which version do you use? I could not find the parse_options in the documentation either.

Comment: @callmeSteve They're supposed to be [pyarrow options](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.ConvertOptions.html#pyarrow.csv.ConvertOptions) e.g. `df = pl.from_arrow(pa.csv.read_csv(..., convert_options=pa.csv.ConvertOptions(decimal_point=",")))`

Comment: @jqurious thanks for clarifying, and it is also a working proposition. just quickly measuring over the option proposed by ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ and the pyarrow is about 3 times slower.

Comment: @callmeSteve Yeah, using `pyarrow` is a "workaround" - polars has its own csv parser, designed for "speed" - it just doesn't have this feature yet as has been mentioned in other comments.

Comment: Apologies if it sounded harsher than I intended. It was just to indicate that while this workaround is working and is helpful, I most likely won't be using it.  :)

Comment: Not a problem - I didn't interpret it as harsh at all.